# Android NavigationView drawer not closing

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

Implementing a NavigationView drawer - I am able to generate the drawer and see it, but cannot close it with swiping.  Additionally, the NavigationItemSelectedListener does not appear to be set up correctly, as I cannot detect click events on the items.

MainActivity.java

```
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout navDrawerLayout;
private ListView navDrawerList;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItemList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle navDrawerToggle;

    private void setupNavDrawer() {
    this.navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            Utility.showDebugToast(String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
            if(item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            navDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });
    this.navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    this.navDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    this.navDrawerItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.navDrawerItemList.add(new NavDrawerItem("NAME", NavDrawerItemType.NAME));
    this.navDrawerItemList.add(new NavDrawerItem("Create Mesh", NavDrawerItemType.CREATE_MESH));
    this.navDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_item, R.id.drawer_tab_text, this.navDrawerItemList));

    this.navDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, navDrawerLayout, R.string.accept, R.string.accept) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(view);
        }
    };

    this.navDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(navDrawerToggle);
    navDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

activity.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/purpose_background" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/appbar_grey"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                style="@style/LobbyTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_box"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:hint="@string/search_editText_placeholder"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/action_search_button"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/search_button"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_lobby_container">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lobby_search_area"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".Lobby"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/grid_fragment"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.nhaarman.supertooltips.ToolTipRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mesh_list_tooltip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <include android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             layout="@layout/spinner_overlay"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_fragment_button"
        android:background="@color/background_white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:alpha=".9"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                  android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                  android:background="#000"
                  android:alpha="0.7"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/drawer_tab"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_icon_statusbar"
    app:border_color="#FF000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_tab_text"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profile_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why can't I slide the Drawer in and out?

Comment: You have zero `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`s in your layouts. Perhaps thats why.

Comment: could you post the full activity.xml

Comment: @Shark please see edited xml

Comment: Do you have `@Override onBackPressed()` on your MainAcitivty ?

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier
     public void onBackPressed() {
  if (this.dialogContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
   this.hideDialog();
  } else {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   startActivity(intent);
  }
 }

Comment: It's not the whole thing, i dont see the drawerlayout closure, `</DrawerLayout>`

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier apologies, edited

Comment: The `NavigationView` must be a direct child of the `DrawerLayout`. You have it inside the `CoordinatorLayout`. That is, move it to after the closing `CoordinatorLayout` tag.

Answer (score 5):

With regards to the drawer closing behaviour, I expect this is to do with the structure of your `activity.xml`.

As per [the guidance here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html):

> To use a `DrawerLayout`, position your primary content view as the first child with a width and height of `match_parent`. Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the `layout_gravity` appropriately.

So this is saying that in your case where you have a content section and one drawer, the DrawerLayout should have two children; first the content, then the drawer. In your xml currently, the `DrawerLayout` only has one child, everything is in the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Try moving your `NavigationView` outside of the `CoordinatorLayout` so your activity looks something like this:

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <CoordinatorLayout>
        content
    </CoordinatorLayout>

    <NavigationView>
        drawer stuff
    </NavigationView>
</DrawerLayout>
```